# Usage of $data in php/yii where clause

Tags: php, yii, where-clause, database-relations

In a category view file, in Yii, ID  I'm trying to post the items related to that category. As I need to customize it quite a bit I'm using my own setup instead of e.g. ListView.

What I need in short is that the query extracts items that has the same category ID as the category selected. The ID/ number is stored in the URL (but without ?'s in it) and it shows up correctly, when I echo it normally.

```
$cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$cmd->select('dk_name, dk_text, idCategory, picture, idProgramGame, points')
->from('programsgames')
->where('idCategory = "'.$model->idcategory.'"')
->order('points DESC');
```

This particular piece of code generates a blank page. In my 100 other attempts it has been blank, a PHP syntax error or all categories only showing listings from category no. 0 no matter what category that really has been selected. The latter one the most frequent.

Comment: try `->where('idCategory=:categoryID', array(':categoryID'=>$model->idcategory))` and make sure $model->idcategory is not null , try var_dump($model->idcategory) to make sure its has a valid category id indeed

Comment: Show more code describing how model variable comes and how id/number extracted from url. Also verify if $model->idcategory is not null. As it will generate fatal error.

Comment: Thank you Sakhunzai, that worked like a charm - you just made my day! :) Sorry for leaving out information Kuldeep, I did however confirm that $model->idcategory before asking the question.